# jQuery, Set Item In One Page, Display It In Another

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML page with a textbox named "workArea":

```
<button id="saveWork">Save Your Work</button>

<textarea id="workArea" cols="80" rows="40">
User edits text here.
</textarea>
```

I want to use jQuery to, when user clicks button "saveWork":

1. change the button to a confirmation that user's work is saved (is working)
2. save the value inside textbox "workArea" to local storage under 'workData' (not working)

> var saveConfirm = "Your work has been saved!";
>
> $("#saveWork").click(function() {
>
> ```
>  $('#saveWork').replaceWith(document.createTextNode(saveConfirm)).show();
>
>  localStorage. setItem ('workData',document.getElementById('workArea').value);
> ```
>
> });

Then, on a new HTML page, display the saved value inside "workArea" in another textbox for the user to continue working on.

Which I figure is something to do with putting this inside a script tag on the new HTML page...

> $(document).ready(function() { localStorage.getItem('workData'); });

I am unable to get the new HTML page to display anything.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: alert(localStorage.getItem('workData')); It is working.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/PX8qm/)**

```
$('#Output').val(localStorage.getItem('workData'));
```

Refresh the page after you Click on 'Save your work', you will get the output in the small text area.